# MySQL php connect failure

Tags: php, mysql, hostname

I have the following php code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("server19.0hosting.org","user","password","dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM dbtable");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Nume</th>
<th>Teme facute</th>
<th>Teme nefacute</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Nume'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Teme facute'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Teme nefacute'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I run it online, I get the following message:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'u536268762_alex'@'srv19.main-hosting.com' (using password: YES) in /home/u536268762/public_html/index.html on line 2 Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'u536268762_alex'@'srv19.main-hosting.com' (using password: YES)
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/u536268762/public_html/index.html on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/u536268762/public_html/index.html on line 18
>
> Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/u536268762/public_html/index.html on line 28

Can please anyone help me?
Also, is it the right hostname the one I wrote there before user?

Comment: So how can we help you? Provide a password? Write a letter to a support?

Comment: what should i change in order to make it display the right thing? i mean the content of the table?

Comment: check your connection parameters are correct..

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan how can i do that? i am a beginner and that's why i'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you should have given some host information, I'll assume certain things (if necessary) and type in something here.

1. If your php script is on the same server, which has the database (the most common thing with all shared services) then you can simply use localhost, e.g;

   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","dbname");
2. The possible reasons for Access Denied are:

   - Username or Password is wrong.
   - Username is not given permissions to connect to the database. (You usually do this while creating a new database.)

Comment: i've tried using the localhost instead but i'm getting the same error

Comment: Yes you get it because of the wrong credentials... Where is your website hosted? local or web cpanel?

Comment: i found the hostname in the MySQL section of my hoster. i'm using cpanel hosting from hourb.thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in this statement.

mysqli_connect("server19.0hosting.org","user","password","dbname");

mysli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "databasename");

check this parameters are correct(check with the person or admin who gave you this details)
  server19.0hosting.org(hostname) is correct
  user(username) is correct
  password(password) is correct
  dbname(databasename) is correct

Comment: how can i find my hostname? i mean is it the site's hostname?

Comment: it's where you database server is running

Comment: I think you need to ask your hosting provider for this connection parameters

Comment: oh i found what hostname i was supposed to write. thanks for the help